# How to do seamless integration (within the website) of PayU payment gateway in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, payment

How to do seamless integration of PayU payment gateway in Magento??
i.e All payment information should be provided within the website.

Cant see relevant stuff on google. Please help

Comment: Are you sure you tried to search? "PayU magento" gives a lot of results like these two:  
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payu-gecad-epayment.html  

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payu-account-payment-extension-1.html

Comment: @Jens W : Thanks for helping, but actually the extensions which you suggested are for non-seamless integration i.e. they will take me to the payU payment page and there I have to fill all credit card and debit card details. But what I need is seamless integration i.e. all payment details should be filled within the website.

Comment: Hello Shivam, did you get this to work? Could you add some details please...

Comment: Actually, my client's requirement got changed while working on this .. they switched from Payu to ICICI payment  gateway. But for your bank codes query all I know is that payu provides a list of all bank codes which also we need to send alongwith other parameters. However not so sure about this stuff as never performed.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but worth answering in case anyone else has the same question.

I called up payU and I was told that the seamless integration is the same except that you add two more params along with the existing one.

Here is the email they Sent:

> Hi 
>   For Seamless integration , You need to post two more parameter 'pg' and 'bankcode'.
>   You need to create your own UI as well for that.

Also make sure that you do send the `ccnum`, `ccvv`, `ccnum` and other relevant credit card details as the user inputs all the details on  your site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If the goal is to make a *direct payment* without having to see the PayU form, what should the *bankcode* value be? Even after adding all the mandatory parameters (ccnum, ccname, ccvv etc), the PayU page still shows up. Any idea how to really make a 'seamless payment'??

Comment: It shouldn't show up the form if the fields are set fine. I integrated it in my previous project and it just worked fine for me. For credit card payment - u need to pass all the form params and two additional params to be set as - bankcode='cc' and pg='cc'. That should do.

Comment: I could give u the list of params to be sent for each payment type if the above doesn't work. Let me know

Comment: @PamioSolanky what should be the action url ??

Comment: @PamioSolanky i want to implement seamless integration in my website using php can you help me

Comment: @kunal I did this 2.5 years ago. I dont know if I can be of help, however, pls let me know how I can help :)

Comment: i think you have code can you send me how to implement ... it will be helpful for me . thanks @PamioSolanky

Comment: @kunal unfortunately I dont have that. It was for a client project :)

Comment: so you can't help me @PamioSolanky